# Cell array vectorization in Matlab

Tags: string, matlab, replace, cell, vectorization

I have a cell array that contains string.

Those individual string needs to be processed, like for example:

```
 a  = {'1,2','12';'2,3','23'}
```

in which, comma should be removed from the string.

I don't know if what's the speed of using for loop compared with using vectorization.

But how can I achieve that using vectorization?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `strrep` to replace characters in a string, like this:

```
EDU>> a = {'1,2','12';'2,3','23'}
a = 
    '1,2'    '12'
    '2,3'    '23'
EDU>> strrep(a,',','')
ans = 
    '12'    '12'
    '23'    '23'
```